# Probability Notation $1\{Y_i \leq y\}$

Tags: probability, notation

I am reading a paper which references an outcome $Y_i$ for individual $i$. There is an associated function $h_i(y) = 1\{Y_i \leq y\}$, which is taken in expectation over all $i$. Is $h_i(y)$ just an indicator of whether $Y_i \leq y$?

Comment: Yes, it is a common notation for indicator functions of an event in probability literature. A typical variant: $\mathbb{1}_{\{Y_i \leq y\}}$.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is a common notation in probability literature for the indicator function of a given event. Typical variant: $\mathbb{1}_A$ for some event $A$.